# Enviar datos de PHPMailer a Correo Electronico

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Sucede que mediante los ejemplos buscados intente enviar un correo mediante un formulario.

Esto es lo que llevo, pero al enviar o al hacer la prueba no me envía los datos al Email, esto es lo que tengo en el código:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'Dar el acceso a mi cuenta de gmail';
$mail->Password = 'la contraseña de mi correo';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 553;

$mail->setFrom('Correo desde donde se envia', 'N3GAS');
$mail->addAddress('correo al que se dirige', 'Joe User');

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Asunto muy importante';
$mail->Body    = 'Este es un correo de prueba!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Yo solo quiero ver donde queda';

$mail->send();
    echo 'El mensaje se envio correctamente';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Hubo un error al enviar el mensaje, fue este: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
?>
```

Seria de mucha ayuda para finalizar el proyecto que estoy desarrollando.

Comment: Sí no lanza una exception, puede que el problema este en la configuración, mayormente suele pasar que el puerto, el usuario, la contraseña o otro dato esta mal.

Comment: Y si todos los datos están verificados y no hay ningún error, cual seria esa otra cosa que puede que este mal?

Comment: y cuál es el stacktrace del error? Edita tu pregunta y agregalo por favor

Comment: Trata enviarlo sin el SMTPSecure y usa un sendmail local del servidor, para ver si lo envía.

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048485/5215609